# How can I set the tslint.json file location in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, tslint

I would like to set my tslint.json location to something other than the workspace root, i.e. "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/". It seems that tslint only works in vscode with tslint in the root directory. Is it possible to change this to another loaction?

Answer (score 2):

Click File -> Preferences -> Settings

Add this line into the preferences:

```
"tslint.configFile": "path to tslint"
```

Comment: Thank you! (I can't upvote the answer to my own question right now because my rep is still too low). I see that this setting was added recently (8 Sept 2017) in release/1.0.1 [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-tslint/releases/tag/release%2F1.0.1).